# Amazon Redshift: Re-occurring date for public holiday table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a table for the public holiday for the countries we deal with. However, I want the dates to be re-occurring so that I can apply a date key for each.

For example, if I have `2018-06-16` and `2018-12-25` as a public holiday, then I want the table to auto-generate `2019-06-16` and `2019-12-25` and so on without me adding it manually each time.

Anyone knows how this can be done in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: In my country, we have holidays such as the 4th Thursday in November and the first Monday in September.  In some people's religions, they have a holiday that is something like the first Sunday of the first full moon after the vernal equinox.  In others, it might be the second new moon after the winter equinox.  In other words, holidays are not so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift uses (mostly) standard SQL. There is nothing special in Redshift that makes this more or less possible than any other SQL database.

SQL does not have an "auto-generate" command. While you could do fancy stuff with `generate_series()`, this will not work on Redshift.

It's probably easier just to download a list of holidays from somewhere and upload it to the table.